# Test level shifter with Arduino and some data

Tags: arduino-mega, led

Below is a reference to a logical level bi-directional converter (aka level shifter) I purchased on Ebay.  I've soldered the 12 pins (6 for each piece) to the level shifter so that it fits on my bread board.

http://www.ebay.com/itm/121868205078?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT

This may sound trivial, but I'd like to troubleshoot the level shifter with communication both ways (Rx and Tx) to make sure it's working properly.  I've got a constant 4.85v (5V) going to the HV pin, and a constant regulated 3.24V (3.3V) going to the LV pin, along with ground to both GND pins.  Right now, I'm using pin0 (Rx) and pin1 (Tx) on the Arduino Mega 2560.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("Test");
}
```

How can I test this level shifter without any fancy components?  How could I write a program to toggle an LED both on LV1 and HV1 pins, by modifying the program above?  Please note, that even though the Arduino runs on 5V, I am not using the Arduino as my HV power source.

## EDIT (per comment 3 by @Paul):

Test:

- Burn blank sketch into Arduino
- Connect 5V (Arduino 5V) to HV pin
- Connect GND (Arduino GND) to GND pin on same side as HV pin
- Connect 3.3V to LV pin
- Connect GND (from 3.3V power source) to GND pin on same side as LV
  pin
- Connect Arduino Tx pin to channel 1 (HV1)
- Connect Arduino Rx pin to channel 2 (HV2)
- Short channel 1 to channel 2 with jumper wire

When all of this is connected, and I open the Serial Monitor on Arduino IDE, anything I type will echo back exactly what I typed.  And when I disconnect one of these jumpers, it doesn't echo back.  So it seems to work.

Comment: Try to perform a "loop-back test" simply send a character over the Tx line through the converter (and back through the converter) into the Rx line. And check if you receive back what you send.

Comment: @Paul - I've connected HV1 (channel 1) to pin 0 (Rx) on the Arduino, and HV2 (channel 2) to pin 1 (Tx) on the Arduino.  What hardare do I put between LV1 and LV2 on the low voltage side of the level shifter to ensure the ASCII character comes back?

Comment: an 0 Ohm resistor ;)
Basically anything that is conductive, a wire preferably. The bits will then travel `from output Tx -> HV1 (high) -> shifter LV1 (to low) -> wire -> shifter LV2 (to high) ->HV2 -> input Rx` if that succeeds, you can safely assume it's working for UART and that it's bi-directional.

Comment: Haha!  I guess the saying goes "Keep It Simple Steve" .. or is that last word incorrect?

Comment: A 0 Ohm's resistor is a resistor that has "no resistance". Which is basically a (short) wire. Check this "tutorial" (http://www.instructables.com/id/Loopback-Test-For-Arduino-Uno/?ALLSTEPS)

Comment: One note here.  I'm using the Arduino, rather than a UART (as in comment by @Paul).  Hopefully your comment holds true when using the Arduino.  Is the Arduino and UART both 5V, which would connect in the same way to the HV pin on the level shifter?

Comment: I'm sorry, UART or USART is the "low level hardware" behind the hardware serial port (Rx and Tx pins). So yes, we're on the same line (:

Comment: @Paul - shorting channel 1 to channel 2 worked!  Does my "Test" in my EDIT look accurate to you?

Comment: if the signal goes from Tx to HV1 to LV1 to jumper to LV2 to HV2 to rx, you can safely assume that the component works. You might want to check the voltages, if they really are around 5V and around 3.3V.
But yes, you've tested/proven that this component will work for serial communication.

Comment: So, yes it seems right to me. You are shorting channel 1 LV and channel 2 LV? From your notes it could also be HV. But both should work neverthless.

Comment: Yes, I basically made a short circuit from LV1 to LV2 with a short jumper wire/cable on my breadboard.  I typed "Hello" and the Serial Monitor echoed back "Hello".  When I removed the short, it didn't echo back "Hello".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to write any program.

First, note that this is (or at least purports to be) an I2C level shifter. This means that it does *not* actively pull up anything; it only actively pulls down. You are supposed to provide pull-ups somewhere in your circuit.

To test it, pull up HV1 and LV1 with 10K resistors to HV and LV respectively; measure the voltage on both sides to verify you are pulling to ~5V and ~3.3V respectively.

Ground HV1, check that LV1 is low.

Ground LV1, check that HV1 is low.

Ta-dah!

Comment: The pull-ups are already on the board, as far as I can see. Though, I'm not entirely sure if you can use an I2C level shifter for UART.

Comment: @Gerben the resistors, are used for the (bi-directional) voltage conversion. I've got a similiar board (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12009) which works for uart, logic and spi (haven't tried I2C but it should be fine).

Comment: @JayEye - When you say "pull up HV1 and LV1 with 10K resisters" do I put a 10K ohm resister between the HV1 pin and some something else, and another 10K ohm resister between the LV1 pin and something else?  Do I need a "something else" or am I just measuring the voltage drop where the "something else" is on the low voltage side and high voltage side of channel 1?

Comment: In addition to testing the voltage, I'd also like to ensure data is passed back and forth.  That's ultimately what I'm after here.  I've updated the title of the question to reflect that.

Comment: @MacGyver edited the answer to make that clear

Comment: if you wan to use this for anything other than i2c, get a proper level converter.

Comment: why would it not pass data? if you make sure that a high and a low on either side results in the corresponding signal, you're good to go.

Comment: What applications should one use an i2c for?  What is a better level shifter for other applications, that this would not work for?  Two days ago, I didn't know what a level shifter was.  :-)

Comment: at the risk of angering the moderators, I'll point to actual products:
https://www.adafruit.com/products/1875 for general-puprose shifting, and 
https://www.adafruit.com/products/757 for I2C level shifting.

Read the documentation they provide, they'll explain everything you need to know.

I am not affiliated with Adafruit; I just find them convenient, as we are both in NYC and even the cheapest shipping results in two-day delivery!!

Comment: @JayEye - does "pull up" mean to go from a low voltage to high voltage, and "pull down" mean go from high voltage to low voltage?

Comment: No, "pull up" means that it's connected through a resistor to "postive" so that, if no device is driving it low, it will be defaulted to postive. You might want to check some tutorials on it. But, it's not required for communication with Rx/Tx lines.

Answer (score 1):

@paul i have done some but when i connect channel1 to channe2 via jumper wire arduino stop working and text stop coming on serial monitor.