# Testing of voltage level converter with arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, electronics

[image][image]I am having a problem I am testing logic level shifter https://ewall.com.pk/product_view/IIC-I2C-Logic-Level-Converter-Bi-Directional-Module-5V-to-3.3V/910. I have followed the procedure as given in this post [Test level shifter with Arduino and some data](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/23774/test-level-shifter-with-arduino-and-some-data). But I am getting opposite result when I connect LV1 to LV2 arduino stop uploading and give error and nothing displays on serail monitor. Kindly help me.

Comment: Please post your circuit schematic.  It's not at all clear what you are doing.

Comment: Apparently you did not completely follow the description at [Test level shifter with Arduino](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/23774/test-level-shifter-with-arduino-and-some-data) as that states that you need to upload a blank sketch _before_ connecting the Arduino serial port to the level shifter, not after (that will not work but that's as expected). Did you also add pullups as described in the answer? Also, a schematic would really help.

Comment: i have not added pullups. Sorry but i don't know how to add pull ups and their purpose. I just followed the edited solution of post.

Comment: In electronic logic circuits, a pull-up resistor or pull-down resistor is a resistor used to ensure a known state of a signal. They are a very fundamental building block in electronics. I would recommend reading this article on pull-up resistors: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/logic/pull-up-resistor.html This will help you understand some of the above comments.

Comment: so that means without adding pullups my circuit is incomplete

Comment: Someone please guide me .